# Can we ask questions about DnD Next?

Tags: discussion

Simple question:  I play tested DnD Next the other day, and I have a bunch of questions about how to understand certain rules/monsters charachter sheets etc.

Are we allowed to ask questions about DnD Next PlayTest packets, or are they "too localized"?

Comment: Related: [Are we allowed to post excerpts from the 5e D&D playtest?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1511/2965)

Answer (score 11):

Go for it!

I believe it is an RPG :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but there needs to be some consistency with the tags.  So far we have dnd-5e and dnd-next.  There really is no need for both of these...

Comment: There may or may not be a need for both of the tags. Is dnd-next only the playtesting and beta version, or is it the name it will actually have when it's released?

Comment: If that's the case, could dnd-next be changed to something more explanatory.  Maybe dnd-5e-playtest or something similar?

Comment: I don't know if that is the case or not.

Comment: @GMNoob No one has confirmed the name of the fifth edition of Dungeons & Dragons. I figure one will end up a synonym of the other.

Comment: @Jadasc Synonyms? I can imagine quite a fraction of questions tagged [DnD-Next] wouldn't apply to [DnD-5e] (if/when it comes out), as the rules are likely to change.

Comment: +1 for the answer. As hinted in my other comment, imho the site needs a tag **[DnD-next]** or something alike for questions about the playtest ruleset, leaving the **[DnD-5e]** tag for that particular future version. The reason being: questions may very well be tagged in either one seperately, or both. (As much as I dislike the term "DnD Next" :D)

Comment: @Jeroen Synonyms. It's a function of StackExchange that allows one tag to redirect to another.

Comment: @Jadasc Yes, I understand :), but I don't agree: they shouldn't be synonyms, unless the current "D&D Next" ruleset turns out to become the *exact* "D&D 5th ed" ruleset.